# Need Columns name From Entity framework Using String table name c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

```
public List<string> GetColumnsForTable(string table)
    {
        var context = _unitOfWork.GetContext();

        var names = typeof(table).GetProperties()
                .Select(property => property.Name)
                .ToArray();

        return names ;
    }
```

Type of need type of entity object but i have string selected from drop down

```
typeof(table).GetProperties()
```

Is there any other way to get columns from entity framework  in c#

Comment: Make a switch that returns the correct type of table Object depending on the string. Pass the object to GetColumsForTable.

Comment: I have hundred of tables

Comment: Don't use a `switch`, use a `Dictionary`. EF isn't really designed to handle generic tables, but rather specific tables with known columns and types and relationships. Also, what is wrong with what you are doing? (Or is it just bad grammer in your question?)

Answer (score 0):

A example. You can use reflection to get the right type of object

Lets say the object is in `namespace People.Family`

and class `Dad`

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("People.Family.Dad");
var names = myType.GetProperties().Select(pro => pro.Name).ToArray();
```

You will still face the problem that you have to specify all the object namespaces and all. Hope it gives you a idea of whats possible.